# Jquery: how to automatically force a textbox to keyup in every 1 hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**I want to automatically fire the below function on every 1 hour. This is actually for currency converter, currently my below function takes action only if users enter/changes any value in the first textbox, **what i want is , below function should automatically call on every one hour, one hour timer time count should start when any changes happen in the textbox***
 *

My function looks like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#from_amount").keyup(function()
        {  
           //my currency converter function goes here

        ----------------------
        ----------------------
```

Comment: Every hour? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @remyabel on every hour i am trying to make the first textbox(#from_amount) to be keyup automatically. Because i have written a function to get output when the first textbox gets `keyup'

Comment: @undefined that is not the answer of my doubt. Please read my question once again i updated it.

Comment: If you're trying to get the latest conversion rates from somewhere every hour may I suggest using a scheduled task or cron job to fetch this rather than doing it with JS? If you have access to set this kind of thing up (depending on your hosting) it could save you a ton of effort

Comment: @remyabel I think he's trying to write an application that would run inside a browser on a big screen in a bank or something and the price will be updated automatically on keyup ... It's nice to see people doing these kinda stuff using web technologies!!!

Comment: I think the question should be updated to -> `fire a function when a new hour start.` You will have to get the client's date/hour (I think it's possible in JS) and bind it to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
function currencyConverter(e){
    //do stuff

    if(e && e instanceof jQuery.Event){
        //the function is triggered from the keyup event
    }
}

var handle = setInterval(currencyConverter, 3600000); //one hour in milliseconds

$(function(){
    $("#from_amount").keyup(currencyConverter);
});
```

If you want to stop the interval:

```
clearInterval(handle);
```

---

If you want to start the timer on a "new hour", you could to something like this (untested):

```
setInterval(function(){

    var now = new Date(),
        newHour = now.getMinutes() === 0 && now.getSeconds === 0;

    if(newHour){

        //trigger 1 hour interval
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Technically this is correct - but I think he's after it being fired on the hour i.e. at 1pm, 2pm, 3pm, rather than every hour after the page is opened (but we're yet to get confirmation of this).

Comment: So does your answer will fire the function `currencyConverter` on every 1hour automatically and it should count 1 hour when users enters value inside the first texbox?

Comment: @Ashutosh DO you want it to fire each time the clock switches to a new hour? This timer starts when the users enters the page.

Comment: @Johan so inside the `if(newHour){` my keyup function goes. You mean inside it i will paste my above keyup function.

Comment: @Ashutosh If you paste `setInterval(currencyConverter, 3600000);` inside the if case it will run `currencyConverter()` every hour at hour:00:00. Assuming my code is correct ;)

Comment: @Johan Your code is will fire on every one hour for the clock time i.e 1 pm 2pm 3pm. But i want one hour  time should  count after detecting the keyup event from first textbox any changes happen in the textbox

Comment: @Ashutosh I've made an update, you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: Okay, i will implement it after sometime. And let you know. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

An hour is a long time for this... but I've used the following in projects before:

`window.setInterval(check_for_messages, 60000);`

The number is the length of time in miliseconds, so this runs the "check_for_messages" function every 1 minute.    The check_for_messages function is an ajax call that checks a database and updates a field on the website.

I don't know how much luck you'll have with 1 hour using this method though.

Answer (score 0):

then use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function of javascript, like

```
setInterval(function currencyConverter(){
//your currency conversion code here
},3600000);
```

Comment: hi Ashutosh, Am not that kind of person to copy others answers and paste as my answer.I edited my answer with example only,before i had given link to w3schools setTimeout() only

Comment: Okay, Vote up for my question please.

Comment: You got your answer right, for what purpose i need to vote up your question, and firstly accept the best suited answer for your question because it helps another persons in future.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can make a timer to trigger a function after a hour:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 1 hour
}, 3600000);
```